# Nodejs - issue with a response

Tags: google-places-api

//    I am unable to get the data from https.get into a variable
// We need to assign the httpd return to the global.city variable.

```
   global.city ;
   https.get(url, function(response) {
     var body ='';
     response.setEncoding("utf8");
     response.on('data', function(chunk) {
       body += chunk;
       //console.log(body);
     });

   }).on('error', function(e) {
     console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   }).on('response',function(f){
     console.log("lets dance");
   }).on('end', function() {
      var places = JSON.parse(body);
        locations = places.results;
        return locations ;
        global.city = locations ; // I get the data here.
        console.log(global.city);
        /* the data is seen here */
    });;

   console.log(global.city); // No response outside the function.
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is retrieved asynchronously, so when you print the result (`console.log(global.city);`) the data is not available yet.

This is how you do it:

```
global.city ;
   https.get(url, function(response) {
     var body ='';
     response.setEncoding("utf8");
     response.on('data', function(chunk) {
       body += chunk;
       //console.log(body);
     });

   }).on('error', function(e) {
     console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   }).on('response',function(f){
     console.log("lets dance");
   }).on('end', function() {
      var places = JSON.parse(body);
        locations = places.results;
        return locations ;
        global.city = locations ; // I get the data here.
        console.log(global.city);
        /* the data is seen here */
        goOn();
    });;

function goOn() {
    // continue your code here
    console.log(global.city); // global.city has value now 
}
```

Hope this helps, but I suggest you look up how Javascript works.